# AdControl SDK Version 6.1.320.0 is not serving test ads

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am having some issue with AdControl SDK(6.1.320.0) for Windows Phone, and wondering if anybody else is having the issue here. My problem is that AdControl is not displaying test ads in emulator and on device too. I tested on multiple machines, and even created a new test project to try it out.

This is my XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
<my:AdControl AdUnitId="Image480_80" ApplicationId="test_client" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-34,118,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="540" />
</Grid>
```

This is what I did so far:

1. Added erroroccured event of the ad control, and printed the error. it showed "HTTP error status code: NotFound (404)"
2. I checked all capabilities in the manifest. it contains all capabilities because its the default test project.
3. then i tried the same on my work pc, which didnt have Windows Phone SDK and AD SDK before. Its not working there either.
4. then i decompiled Ad SDK for Silverlight assembly, and found the URL of production and testing server.

AdPlacement.ServerUrl = "https://mobileads.msn.com/v3/Delivery/Placement";
AdPlacement.TestServerUrl = "https://mobileads-test.msn.com/v3/Delivery/Placement";

The test server url is not connecting at all. I am using VS2010 ultimate on a Windows 7 x64 ultimate machine.

Any other idea? I contacted psupport AT microsoft DOT com as well, yet to get their reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of emails with MS Ad center support, they could reproduce the issue in-house when trying to connect from outside network. They fixed the issue this afternoon. Its working without any code change from my side. The problem was the ad server that serves test ads "https://mobileads-test.msn.com/v3/Delivery/Placement was not reachable from outside MS network!

Answer (score 0):

I personally never understood the need for test mode. I never use test mode.. just set the correct config for application / ad unit and thats it.

Comment: sorry, i was not talking about testmode property of the adcontrol. that property is no longer needed and not available in the latest Ad SDK. I was talking about AdUnitId and ApplicationId of adcontrol. You cannot run the app in emulator with real ApplicationId for AdControl.  btw, MS Ad Support team acknowledged they could reproduce the issue. few hours later, the test ads started working for me.

Comment: very strange.. i have never had such issues. i have however noticed that emulator does not switch network connection. you need to restart if you want data connection.